# Polynomial Division algorithm using DFT and FFT

Tags: algorithm, fft, proof, polynomials, dft

I am given to polynomials p and q of size n-1 and m-1 where n>=m. I also have the division algorithm below:

```
1. Let n' be the smallest power of 2 greater than n − 1.
2. Use the FFT to compute y = DFTn'(p), and z = DFTn'(q).
3. Compute the n-dimensional vector {y0/z0, y1/z1, . . . , yn0/zn0}.
4. Compute a = DFT^-1 {y0/z0, y1/z1, . . . , yn0/zn0}),
and return this as the coefficient vector for p(x)/q(x)
```

I have to find the cases when this will reconstruct p(x)/q(x) succesfully both when p(x)/q(x) can be represented by a polynomial and when it is an infinite series.

I have no clear idea of how to go about solving this and any help would be appreciated. I've had ideas of maybe computing the FFT and inverse DFT but can't see how I would reach my conclusion

Comment: You could use the convolution theorem right?

Comment: I do not really undertand what you need to proof, but I found this http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polymultiply.pdf. This should get you on your way. good luck

Comment: Thank you, I just need to find cases when the algorithm will reconstruct p(x)/q(x) successful @GijsDenHollander

Comment: This should help you out even more, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380720/is-deconvolution-simply-division-in-frequency-domain.

Comment: how to handle zero or almost zero `q(x)` elements?  resulting in division by zero or overflow. (the link one comment up shines some light on it so +1) I would do standard polynomial division and also the FFT based and compare the results that should give you answer which inputs are doable with this approach.do not forget to compare them with some abs epsilon instead direct comparison due to rounding errors